# signs when computing the determinant of a matrix recursively

Tags: matrices, determinant

As described [here](https://www.mathreference.com/la-det,def.html#:%7E:text=The%20determinant%20can%20be%20defined,determinant%20of%20this%20smaller%20matrix.) the determinant can be computed recursively:

> The determinant can be defined recursively, where the determinant of a $1x1$ matrix is the single entry in that matrix. Given a larger $nxn$ matrix, $M$ delete the **first row** and the $j$th ($0$-indexed) column. This leaves $n-1$ rows and $n-1$ columns. By induction we can compute the determinant of this smaller matrix. This is called a subdeterminant. Multiply the subdeterminant by the $j$th entry of the **first row**, then negate the product if $j$ is odd. Finally, add up all these products as $j$ runs from $0$ to $n-1$ to obtain $det(M)$.

(Note: I paraphrased and changed $j$ from $1$-indexed to $0$-indexed.)

The procedure says to use the **first row**, but truly we can use any row or column. Say we choose the $r$th row ($0 \leq r < n$).

- Let $R$ be the $r$th row of $M$
- Let $M_{\setminus R}$ be matrix $M$ with row $R$ removed
- Let $M_{\setminus R \cup J}$ be matrix $M$ with the row $R$ and the $j$th column removed ($0 \leq j < n$)

Then, we have,

$$
\operatorname{det}(M) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \pm\ R[j] \cdot \operatorname{det}(M_{\setminus R \cup J})
$$

where $R[j]$ is the $j$-th entry of $R$.

And there's an analogous equation if we choose a column instead of a row. Say we choose the $c$th column.

- Let $C$ be the $c$th col of $M$
- Let $M_{\setminus C}$ be matrix $M$ with column $C$ removed
- Let $M_{\setminus C \cup I}$ be matrix $M$ with the column $C$ and the $i$th row removed ($0 \leq i < n$)

$$
\operatorname{det}(M) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \pm\ C[i] \cdot \operatorname{det}(M_{\setminus R \cup I})
$$

where $C[i]$ is the $i$-th entry of $C$.

I'm using the $\pm$ in front of each product because I don't know which products are negated and which aren't. What is the rule? For the row case, is it that if $r + j$ is odd then we negate the product? For the column case, is it that if $c + i$ is odd then we negate the product?

$$
\begin{align}
r=0 &&+ - + - + - + ...\\
r=1 &&- + - + - + - ...\\
r=2 &&+ - + - + - + ...\\
. &&.\\
. &&.\\
. &&.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are right! For the row case, we negate the product if and only if $r+j$ is odd. Similarly, for the column case, we negate the product if and only if $c+i$ is odd.

To be precise, you are using Laplace Expansion of a Determinant.

For Laplace expansion along the ith row, the determinant is calculated as follows:
$$\det(A)=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij}$$

For Laplace expansion along the jth column, the determinant is calculated as follows:
$$\det(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij}$$

I would refer you to the Laplace Expansion section of the Wikipedia page [Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know the name. In your equations, are $i$ and $j$ $1$-indexed? I.e. would the first row correspond to $i = 1$?

Comment: @joseville That’s correct